# Front page - page does not exist

Tags: nodes

Since I moved my web site to another web hosting, Front page won't show their contents.
Problem persists either if I set some other page to be front page in Site Informations.
Do not know what to look. CMS is Drupal 6 updated to 6.28 just today.
I tried to uninstall PATHAUTO module and for once it showed content but on another attempt to open it, there's same problem.
Server supports CURLs

Please help,
I am ready to create some admin account to anyone who can help to resolve this.

Tnx.

Boris

Comment: are you able to access the page that you set as the site front/home page directly with its URL? example if node/100 is set as home does sitename/node/100 take you to the appropriate page? also would it be possible to check what value is set in the `variable` table for `site_frontpage` to ensure anything you set from admin end gets assigned to it, you could either check that by querying or using drush with a command like `drush vget site_frontpage` and last do you have any custom module for setting the site front page?

Comment: I can access to any page with alias or Node ID directly and its appears normal. Problem persists when some page is set to be a front page either with alias or ID.
In variable table I can see that is set exactly what is in Site Information front page field. I changed to another page and in variable table parameter is changed too to that page. I am not using custom modules at all. In front page content is created by views.

Comment: just re-read the question, initially I assumed that the front page returned not found. If only the content, namely blocks are not visible it might be configured in the block display settings perhaps or a specific `page-front.tpl.php` is being used?

Comment: It is probably problem with data base. I installed existing drupal on new dbase and used same theme. Problem is not appears any more. So I have to check my dbase or maybe start over with creating content types, views and contents again.